# python pow function with 1024 bit integers

Tags: python

I want to raise an integer x to the power of (p-1)/2 modulo p, where p is a prime number.
p and x are 1024 bit integers.
There is some theorem (consequence of Lagrange's theorem) which states that the result must be equal to 1, -1 or 0 mod p.

Consider the following code:

```
p = 101524035174539890485408575671085261788758965189060164484385690801466167356667036677932998889725476582421738788500738738503134356158197247473850273565349249573867251280253564698939768700489401960767007716413932851838937641880157263936985954881657889497583485535527613578457628399173971810541670838543309159139
x = 85256449776780591202928235662805033201684571648990042997557084658000067050672130152734911919581661523957075992761662315262685030115255938352540032297113615687815976039390537716707854569980516690246592112936796917504034711418465442893323439490171095447109457355598873230115172636184525449905022174536414781771


print(pow(x, int((p-1)/2), p))
```

with python 3.9.2 it gives

```
27980403064579636028055449870417771181244326459581529717454053960638629219169075321551780381136980928762710368915290204712290597582758394662971100864236376202143782193827974545206195986726913123604423878525492811925195928165327468926425839191512631291796118427230662866781350545453987781889400451930787015913
```

which is not -1 mod p.

With sagemaths, it gives 1, so probably the right result.

So obviously, there is something wrong here. I thought that python was able to handle arbitrary-length integers without any problem. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the division operator `/`. Integers have arbitrary length, but floats don't. When you do `int((p-1)/2)`, it's getting converted to `float` and then back to `int`, so the precision is lost. If you try integer division `//`:

```
pow(x, (p-1)//2, p)
```

it will work as expected.